# Does Adobe AIR work on linux ? how do i install because linux does not support exe format

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash

I am beginner so  have some doubt about Adobe AIR.

1. How do I install my AIR project in linux, or mac os because my project out .air(execute file).os does not support execute file ?
2. Does it support multi language in Adobe air? And one more, how can I embed  css  not use an external css file?
3. Does it support live streaming video in desktop application?  In flash we using adobe media server for streaming video. What about Adobe air?
4. Does it support encryption and decryption in Adobe air? If so, then how do I get compatibility with encryption in php?
5. Is it possible to identify net traffic in Adobe air?

If you know can help with any one please explain. I am waiting always for your valuable answer ...

Comment: It might help if you ask only one question in each SO Question. That way, each can have its own accepted answer, and people can be more focused in their responses.

Comment: ok .RBerteig .Here after i do .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your basic question... yes Adobe AIR does work on Linux.

Google "adobe air linux".

Fire up a Linux PC and go to:

http://get.adobe.com/air/

...you will be given a link to download AIR for Linux.

I use the ExtJS help pages with Linux.  It installs beautifully.  It is an ELF 32-bit executable, not a Windows .EXE.

$ file AdobeAIRInstaller.bin
AdobeAIRInstaller.bin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

TWO. Yes.  Google "adobe air muiltilingual".  It will take you to:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/localizing_flex_air_apps.html

THREE. Yes.  Google "adobe air streaming video".  Links such as:

http://www.streamingmedia.com/article.asp?id=9884

...talks about how this is done.

FOUR. Yes.  Google "adobe air encryption library".  Links such as:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html

...talk about storing encrypted data.

But if you're talking about encrypting your on-the-wire traffic, then AIR will certainly support HTTPS I'm quite sure.

FIVE. I'm not sure what you mean by this last question: "is it possiable to identified net traffic".  What kind of net traffic, and what do you mean by "identify"?

Comment: thank you the.jxc very very much for very valuable answer to us .

Comment: is it support Mac os also he.jxc

Comment: thank you the.jxc . is it possiable Interned connection handling through Application

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific I'm afraid.  What kind of internet connection?  http?  https?  ftp?  rtp?  ldap?  udp?  sctp?

Comment: http kind of connection 
like speed of data transfer and net connection is there or not . just for throw alert msg to end user like "internet connection not now in your system so you cant use desktop application  now "